# Add a dynamic textbox inside the listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" x:Name="lstbxindex" SelectionMode="Extended" Foreground="White" FontSize="20px" Height="241" BorderBrush="#555555" Margin="10,34,16,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" Background="#555555" 
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
              <Label x:Name="items" Content="{Binding ProjectRow.Name}" Margin="35,0,0,0" MouseDoubleClick="items_MouseDoubleClick" Foreground="White"></Label>
           </WrapPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

when I Doubleclick the listboxitems, The label turn to change a textbox using this textbox change listboxitems which is selected.Then I click enter the textbox turns to again a label. How can Add dynamictextbox inside the listbox which is bind the values from codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this. Put both controls inside the datatemplate with one collapsed.

Then in the code behind switch the visibility properties. Both are bound to the same property so will keep in sync with one another.

XAML

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Name="TextBlockName" Text="{Binding ProjectRow.Name}" MouseDown="TextBlockName_OnMouseDown" ToolTip="Double click to edit"/>
        <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed" Name="TextBoxName" Text="{Binding ProjectRow.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Code behind

```
private void TextBlockName_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickCount == 2)
            {
                this.TextBlockName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                this.TextBoxName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

    private void TextBoxName_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextBlockName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.TextBoxName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a custom Grid and use it:

```
public class NGrid : Grid
{
    public NGrid()
    {
        _textBox = new TextBox { Visibility = Visibility.Hidden };
        _label = new Label();
        _textBox.KeyDown += _textBox_KeyDown;
        Children.Add(_textBox);
        Children.Add(_label);
    }

    private void _textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isEditMode && e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            _textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            _label.Content = _textBox.Text;

        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2 && _isEditMode == false)
        {
            _textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Keyboard.Focus(_textBox);
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    bool _isEditMode;
    TextBox _textBox;
    Label _label;
}
```

Didn't test it, but should work.